# Determining the level of Android permission

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I have some Android permissions which I would like to know to which permision PROTECTION LEVEL they belong. Does anybody know how can this be checked? For example I need to know the PROTECTION LEVEL of `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission, but I would like to check many more.

**EDIT:**

I see that I didn't put it clearly: What I mean is not an API level with which permission was introduced, but permission protection level, one of four: Normal, Dangerous, Signeture, Signature Or System. It determines for example how this permission is presented to user during the application installation. How can I check to which protection level certain permission belongs?

Answer (score 8):

A list of default permissions with the associated protection levels can be found in the latest source here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Example:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.NETWORK"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_createNetworkSockets"
    android:label="@string/permlab_createNetworkSockets" />
```

Keep in mind they could be changed by the OEM.

Answer (score 5):

```
getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(name,  0).protectionLevel
```

Answer (score 1):

In [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) you can see all the permissions of android. 
The level you mark it here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what i meant. I corrected the question above, so if you have some idea about that, I would appreciate help :)

Comment: image can't visible

Answer (score 0):

For `Android-Permission`..

- To enforce permissions, various parts of the system invoke a
  permission validation mechanism to check whether a given application
  has a specied permission. The permission validation mechanism is
  implemented as part of the trusted system process, and invocations of
  the permission validation mechanism are spread throughout the API.
  There is no centralized policy for checking permissions when an API
  is called. Rather, mediation is contingent on the correct placement
  of permission validation calls.

  [image]
- **Permission checks are placed in the API implementation in the system
  process.** When necessary, the API implementation calls the
  permission validation mechanism to check that the invoking
  application has the necessary permissions. In some cases, the API
  library may also redundantly check these permissions, but such checks
  cannot be relied upon: applications can circumvent them by directly
  communicating with the system process via the RPC stubs. Permission
  checks therefore should not occur in the API library. In- stead, the
  API implementation in the system process should invoke the permission
  validation mechanism.

Also just go through with this documents for more info [Android-Permission](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~afelt/android_permissions.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. I know already this stuff about permissions. I corrected the question above to make it more clear about my intentions. Please check if you know the answer.

Comment: @user370305 Too difficult to understand. Can you simplify it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the protection level in the [permission documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

[image: android-website]